# How to test IPN on sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a sandbox account on https://developer.paypal.com/ and I want to test ipn.

But where do I enter the IPN for the business account?

I can do a successful test sale but I cannot get the IPN to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup IPN in the sandbox seller account the same way you would a live account.  Just go to http://sandbox.paypal.com and login with the sandbox seller email and password.  Then go into the profile and into IPN settings.  Turn it on and point it to the URL you've got configured.

You can also make use of the IPN Simulator which is included in your developer.paypal.com account.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that URL. I set it up there, but can't get it to work. Please check it out if you have the time here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856785/cannot-get-paypal-ipn-to-work